# Javascript - Display div

Tags: javascript, html, show-hide

I need to check onload if an anchor is within the URL to open a tab if required. The problem is that if a user opens a tab before the onload function gets fired, the tab gets closed and the user needs to open it again. 
How to fix that?

HTML:

```
<body onload="checkurl()">
```

JS:

```
 function checkurl(){
    if (window.location.hash == '#about')
    {
    showhide('secabout');
    }
    else if (window.location.hash == '#contact')
    {
    showhide('seccontact');
    }
    }
```

JS function:

```
var divState = {}; 
function showhide(id) {
    if (document.getElementById) {
        var divid = document.getElementById(id);

        divState[id] = (divState[id]) ? false : true; 
        for (var div in divState){
            if (divState[div] && div != id){ 
                document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none'; 
                divState[div] = false; 
            }
        }
        divid.style.display = (divid.style.display == 'block' ? 'none' : 'block');
    }
}
```

Thanks.
Uli

Comment: Disable the tabs until the onload has triggered...

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that <script> tags inside of <head> execute right away before onload() so try that.

Comment: Yes it does, but that does not help, because at that time, the `<div>` elements does not exist yet, so it will do nothing.

Answer (score 0):

You can call the function with an extra parameter to make sure will show in your load function.

Then check on a global `initialized` variable to check if the function has already been executed by user when running from the `checkurl` function. This is required if the user clicks on a different tab than the one specified in the URL.

Also you need to check on `divState[id]` instead of `divid.style.display == 'block'` when updating `divid.style.display` at bottom.

```
function checkurl(){      
  if (window.location.hash == '#about')      
  {      
    showhide('secabout', true);      
  }      
  else if (window.location.hash == '#contact')      
  {      
    showhide('seccontact', true);      
  }      
}      

var divState = {};   
var initialized = false;
function showhide(id, initialize) {  
  if(initialized && initialize) return;
  initialized = true;
  if (document.getElementById) {  
    var divid = document.getElementById(id);  
    divState[id] = (divState[id]) ? false : true; 
    for (var div in divState){  
      if (divState[div] && div != id){   
        document.getElementById(div).style.display = 'none';   
        divState[div] = false;   
      }  
    }  
    if(initialize){ 
      divid.style.display = 'block';  
    } else { 
      divid.style.display = (divState[id] ? 'block' : 'none');  
    } 
  }  
}
```

Comment: It's not working. If the URL contains for example "#contact" and the tab "#about" gets clicked before the onload function fires, the secabout div doesn't get closed anymore. It stays open.

Comment: You need to check on `divState[id]` instead of `divid.style.display == 'block'` when updating `divid.style.display` at last line. I have updated my code example to fix this. I have also added a global `initialized` variable to control if the user has already selected a tab when onload runs.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It works great on the root of the domain  **http://www.example.com/#team** but the div stays closed if I use it on a subpage such as http://www.example.com/about#team - did I miss something there?

Comment: Try with a slash before the hash: `example.com/about/#team`

Comment: It needs to work with and without a slash. Any ideas how to fix that? Thanks.